# .NET Core WPF app crashes due to SharePoint on commit to Access

Tags: .net, wpf, ms-access, asp.net-core, sharepoint

My C# .NET Core WPF app crashes every time I perform a database operation via C#.  The issue is that once I save in the code, the application tries to perform some operation with our SharePoint site.  But, since the App is used out of network, the App fails to connect to the SharePoint site and crashes the Application.

The App is used not connected to any VPN or network.

The SharePoint site is only accessible through the network.

Why is my Application trying to access the SharePoint site when writing to the Access DB?  How can I turn that off in the code or in Access settings?

[image: bug]